# Magento: Is there some js function that makes equal height for UL list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, extjs

I have Ul list with a different Li height.

[This script](http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/) could help, but I would like to use regular magento js function instead.
If it exists of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

There are only functions that adds odd/even/last classes to lists and tables. So the only solution is to add your function to Magento. I suggest doing it not with jQuery but with prototype as it is included into Magento by default and jQuery is not.